# How do I create a method in Java that returns an enum depending on input?

Tags: java, enums

I have two enums

```
public enum CurrencyOptionEUR {
  EUR_EUR("euro"),
  EUR_GBP("pound");
}
```

and

```
public enum CurrencyOptionAsia {
  ASIA_YEN("yen"),
  ASIA_EUR("euro");
}
```

and their values might overlap as the example show.

What I want is a method that based on an argument returns one or the other enum.
Something like this

```
public enum switchEnum(String country){
    if(country.equals("Japan")) return CurrencyOptionAsia;
    else return CurrencyOptionEur;
}
```

but enum cannot be the return type of a method

What would the best way to implement this behavior?
Thanks

Comment: This very much looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is a strongly typed language, so all variables and return types are required to have an actual type. With this in mind, I would recommend having both enums implement a common interface:

```java
interface CurrencyOption {
}
```

Then modifying your existing enums as follows:

```java
public enum CurrencyOptionEUR implements CurrencyOption {
  // Contents omitted for brevity
}

// Probably should rename this one for consistency
public enum CurrencyAsia implements CurrencyOption {
  // Contents omitted for brevity
}
```

And then using `CurrencyOption[]` as your return type:

```java
public CurrencyOption[] switchEnum(String country){
    if(country.equals("Japan")) return CurrencyAsia.values();
    else return CurrencyOptionEur.values();
}
```

With that said I would like to point out Java has had [built-in support for currencies since version 1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Currency.html), and I would **strongly** recommend using this (or another existing library) instead of creating your own.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense and I will give it a go. The currency was just a way to mask business logic, but the idea remains the same

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: You have to return an Object and then check for the instance in your calling method and parse it accordingly.

But for your example, I wouldn't take this approach anyway. Java has a own [Currency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) class, I'd rather work with that one, since it features `getSymbol()` and `getDisplayName()`. So instead of returning an enum, you'd return a Set of currencies.

Answer (score 0):

All enums implement the interface `Enum`, so you can certainly write a method that returns an enum this way.

```
public Enum<?>[] switchEnum(String country) {
    if(country.equals("Japan")) return CurrencyOptionAsia.values();
    else return CurrencyOptionEur.values();
}
```